# WebBrowser control - How click element on site with javascript?

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, pega

I try many variant, but it don't work. So how I can click on this `element(rowIndex="1")`:

```
<table class="ViewTableStyle" id="ViewTable" onmouseover="return ViewTable_onmouseover()" onclick="return ViewTable_onclick()" hrows="true">
<tr class="listTableRowStyle" style="cursor: hand;" rowIndex="1">
<tr class="listTableRowStyle" style="cursor: hand;" rowIndex="2">
```

I can get  element, but when click by it, I see javascript error: "An error has occurred in the script on this page. Do you want to continue running scripts on this page?"

My code C# is:

```
if(link.GetAttribute("rowIndex")=="1"{
link.InvokeMember("Click")
```

This sample I try too

```
link.RaiseEvent("onClick")
```

Site work on Pega BPM...

Comment: Look at your HTML and highlighting. You are missing a quote somewhere...